# opening directory through IndexReader or IndexSearcher?in lucene

Tags: performance, lucene

what is the difference between these two codes? based on performance oriented and documentation oriented

using directory directly in `IndexSearcher`

```
Analyzer anal = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "", anal);
Query query = parser.parse(queryStr);
Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(NIOFSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir)));
```

using directory in `IndexReader` then opening searcher using that reader

```
Analyzer anal = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "", anal);
Query query = parser.parse(queryStr);
IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(NIOFSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir)), false);
IndexSearcher searcherNew = new IndexSearcher(ir);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IndexSearcher is a lightweight wrapper around an IndexReader. Even if you use the IndexSearcher constructor, [an IndexReader will be open under the hoods](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.5.0/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.java#IndexSearcher.%3Cinit%3E%28org.apache.lucene.store.Directory%29), so you can expect the same performance from your two snippets.

Altough it can be convenient, it is a bad practice to open directly an IndexSearcher over a Directory. Besides, this constructor is deprecated since Lucene 3.5.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, opening the IndexReader is the costly operation. Wrapping an IndexReader in a new IndexSearcher is cheap. So for optimization, you need to carefully manage reuse of IndexReaders, but not necessarily IndexSearchers.